# In SQL table I have a sql script for dropping column which gives error invalid column does not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I a table in SQL database sample_table which contains the following columns:-

Id,first_name,last_email,email,user_type.

Now I want to write a script to drop column user_type if it exists. 
So I have the following script:-

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT *
      FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table'
             and COLUMN_NAME = 'user_type')
 BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE sample_table
    DROP COLUMN user_type
 END
 GO
```

As per the script the if exists condition is right but even though it gives the compile time error **invalid column user_type does not exist** if this script is executed more than once so is there 
some way to skip the error.
If any you please suggest how.
I have tried with sys object also gives the same error.
So I just want to know if there is a way to skip getting this error?
Also is there a way apart from using a dynamic query if any?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick way would be to put the `ALTER TABLE` in a dynamic query

Comment: I want to avoid using dynamic query

Comment: The code is failing to *compile*. You need to move the `ALTER` into a different scope (such as dynamic SQL, as Guido said) in order for the outer part to be *compiled* such that it can perform a *runtime* check of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Comment: "executed more than once" seems to imply you are making a stored procedure. It's a bit "dirty", but I would `ALTER TABLE sample_table ADD COLUMN  user_type int`, then proceed to create/alter the procedure, then drop the column.

Comment: Yeah I know @GuidoG is right but is there any alternative instead of dynamic query

Comment: Are you using fully qualified table name in your alter script. <databasename>.<schema>.<tablename> .  I've had cases with the same table name in different databases

Comment: Yes I have used fully qualified names

Comment: The compiler will check if table and column(s) exist. If **anything** doesn't exist, the compile will fail. So yes the 2nd time you ask it to compile, it fails. The only fix is to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Actually I have CI/CD folder which runs sql script for every build on different enviroments that's why it is getting executed more than once and I dont want error to triggered neither do i plan to use dynamic query because I am trying to find if there is some other approach

Comment: What is the reason you dont want to use dynamic sql ?

Comment: Since Parsing, Validation, Optimization, and Generation of application plan are done at run time so it is less efficient.

Comment: @Hp_issei - nothing is going to avoid the fact that two parts of this code need to be compiled separately. All of the things you've mentioned have to happen a second time because you want to perform a *runtime* check before a later part of the code is compiled. Batches, dynamic SQL, etc. And worrying that dynamic SQL is going to be inefficient when the overhead of the whole script is probably going to be dwarfed by I/O costs (disk storage, network overheads, etc) isn't a good use of time.

Comment: @Damien The script is going to be executed multiple times not just twice because of deployment of scripts on different environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tolerate multiple batches but cannot tolerate dynamic SQL for some reason, you can use `NOEXEC`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table'
       and COLUMN_NAME = 'user_type')
BEGIN
   SET NOEXEC ON
END
GO   
ALTER TABLE sample_table
    DROP COLUMN user_type
GO
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Either way, what's important is that you don't attempt to *compile* the `ALTER TABLE` statement until after you've verified that the necessary objects exist.